# How to login android application using facebook credentials?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, proguard

I tried to log my application using Facebook credentials.It runs without errors but it is not display the username.

Its load the Facebook log in page, but it not display the Facebook name in text View.

I followed [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) Guide lines.

This is the activity class.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state

        @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

              // make request to the /me API
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                    welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");

                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    Log.d("User Name", user.getName());
                  }
                }
              });
            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            }
          }
        });
      }
      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
}
```

I added this two lines to proguard-android.txt as well

```
#-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
#-keepattributes Signature
```

This is the libraries i used

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: I am also using this same code, but i am getting exact result.

Comment: should i add any libraries here? @InnocentKiller

Comment: I have not added any extra library, but i have not added this `#-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
#-keepattributes Signature` line and then also it is working fine for me.

Comment: Can you do one thing after making some change just delete your app completely either from device or emulator then clean your project and run it again. might be this trick works. Because i don't find any problem in your code.

Comment: I removed that two codes from proguard-android.txt file.but its not working.

Comment: did you tried removing app from device , cleaning your project and everything what i mention in my previous comment.

Comment: @InnocentKiller yes i did

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46993/discussion-between-anuruddhika-and-innocentkiller)

Answer (score 0):

Allright here's my solution-

1st import FacebookSDK to ur workspace.

2nd add FacebookSDK to ur project. Right Click on ur project->properties->Android->Library->Add-> FacebookSDK->ok

3rd add FacebookSDK.jar as external jar. Right Click on ur project->properties->Java Build path->Library->Add external jar->[path to ur facebookSDK.jar file]->ok

4th Here's MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnLoginFB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btnLoginFB =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginFB);

btnLoginFB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// start Facebook Login
Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

// callback when session changes state
@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

if (session.isOpened()) {

Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

// callback after Graph API response with user object
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
if (user != null) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, user.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
}).executeAsync();

}

}
});

}
});

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

5th Here's AndroidManmifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mysample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name="com.example.mysample.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
android:value="@string/app_id" />

<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

app_id is the application's ID you've have created on facebook developer account.

After successful login it toast the username.

Comment: I tried your answer. but it says like this. 02-09 08:47:12.461: E/AndroidRuntime(28180): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager
com.facebook.internal.SessionTracker.<init>(SessionTracker.java:76)
com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.finishInit(LoginButton.java:533)
com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.onFinishInflate(LoginButton.java:526)

Comment: and like this error 02-09 08:48:23.661: W/dalvikvm(28699): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
02-09 08:48:23.661: W/dalvikvm(28699): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
02-09 08:48:23.661: I/dalvikvm(28699): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction